# PS script to check status of a service and install a new windows service

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

PS Script Scenario

```
1-> Check if service exists
     -> if doesn't exists
        -> copy item and install windows service and start.
     -> If exists
        -> Stop Windows service & delete it and copy item from folder and Install & start the service.
```

Below is my script

```
$service = Get-Service -Name XXX -Computername YYY
if($service.Status -eq $NULL)
{
    Copy-Item "C:\location\*" "\\yyy\d$\Location" -Force -Recurse
    sc.exe \\yyy create xxx start=auto DisplayName="value"  binPath= D:\Build\test.exe
    sc.exe \\yyy description xxx "value"
    sc.exe \\yyy start xxx
    Write-Host "xxx STARTED"
}
else
{
    sc.exe \\yyy stop xxx
    Write-Host "xxx STOPPED"
    sc.exe \\yyy delete xxx 
    Write-Host "xxx DELETED"
    Copy-Item "C:\Location\*" "\\yyy\d$\Location" -Force -Recurse
    sc.exe \\yyy create xxx start=auto DisplayName="value"  binPath= D:\Build\test.exe
    sc.exe \\yyy description xxx "value"
    sc.exe \\yyy start xxx
    Write-Host "xxx STARTED"
}
```

Is my approach right and I see error if there is no service name XXX. How to override this error and continue with the If condition statement.

Error-

```
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'Spoole'.
At line:1 char:12
+ $service = Get-Service -Name Spoole
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Spoole:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Comment: this seems like a right approach, the only thing that is missing - error handling, your script would still write `xxx STARTED` even if `sc.exe` threw an error, also, there's the [New-Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service) cmdlet, not sure when did it happen to appear. On my opinion this question is too broad to be answered here, thou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
$service = Get-Service -Name XXX -Computername YYY -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

To supress the error.